# Found error in scala in my own implementation of list

Tags: scala

I am implementing my own `List` collection using a generic abstract class `List[+T]`. I want to add a `map` function which changes the list according to a given function :

```
abstract class List[+T] {
  def map[U>:T](f: T => U): List[U] = this match {
    case null => this
    case x :: xs => f(x) :: xs.map(f)
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error in `x :: xs`:

> constructor can not instantiated to expected type.found Scala.collection.immutable .::required List[T]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ? Implement your own `List` collection ?

Comment: yes i want to make a map list such that when i call xs.map(x => x*x) [xs is a list type] it modified my list according to function

Comment: You can not use [`::`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon) since it extends [`immutable.List`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) and not your own `List` type.

Comment: so any suggestion how i can implement this

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your own `List` class ?

Answer (score 1):

Tt first you can read architecture of scala collection
[link](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html)

> To summarize, if you want to fully integrate a new collection class
>   into the framework you need to pay attention to the following points:
>
> - Decide whether the collection should be mutable or immutable.
> - Pick the right base traits for the collection.
> - Inherit from the right implementation trait to implement most collection operations.
> - If you want map and similar operations to return instances of your collection type, provide an implicit CanBuildFrom in your class’s  companion object.

Implementation of map in TraversableLike:

```
def map[B, That](f: Elem => B)
    (implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
  val b = bf(this)
  this.foreach(x => b += f(x))
  b.result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `::` you are trying to match your own `List` against Scala standard library `List`. If you want to use pattern matching, you need to define your own extractor.

You can read more about infix extractors at [The Neophyte's Guide to Scala Part 1: Extractors](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html), paragraph **Infix operation patterns**.

Another nice explanation can be found at [The Scala List extractor demystified](http://blog.lunatech.com/2011/11/25/scala-list-extractor-demystified):

> It turns out that there's a case class called `::` (in the `scala.collection.immutable` package) that extends `List`. One of the many neat things that case classes give you, is a synthetic companion object with an unapply method that can deconstruct instances of that type,